# Parsley Remote validation is not preventing form submission

Tags: angularjs, validation, parsley.js, remote-validation

I am using Parsley Remote validation with angularJS..using the async validator with add new user form is working fine, it uses the API and checks if the user name is already existed, and the email as well, if the user name is there it returns a 200 status, which is not equal to 404 and an error message appears.. BUT when submitting the form, if I check the form.isvalid status it returns true, it is only validating the NON remote options. I am stuck there.

here is the web form

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post" id="AddUserForm"
            data-ui-jq="parsley"
            data-parsley-remote
            data-parsley-priority-enabled="false"
            novalidate="novalidate">
          <fieldset>
              <legend>
                  By default validation is started only after at least 3 characters have been input.
              </legend>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="basic">User Name</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                      <input type="text" name="userName" class="form-control" data-ng-model="user.userName" value=""
                             data-parsley-remote
                             data-parsley-remote-validator='checkusername'
                             data-parsley-trigger="focusout"
                             data-parsley-remote-message="User name is already registerd in the system"
                             required="required" />

                      <span class="help-block">
                          Username must be unique
                      </span>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="email">
                      E-mail
                  </label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" data-ng-model="user.email"
                             data-parsley-remote
                             data-parsley-remote-validator='checkemail'
                             data-parsley-trigger="focusout"
                             data-parsley-remote-message="Email is already registerd in the system"
                             required="required" />
                      <span class="help-block">
                          Email must be unique
                      </span>
                  </div>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="password">
                      Password:
                  </label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control mb-sm" data-ng-model="user.password"
                             data-parsley-trigger="change"
                             data-parsley-minlength="6"
                             required="required" />
                      <input type="password" id="password-r" name="password-r" class="form-control" placeholder="Confrim Password" data-ng-model="user.confirmPassword"
                             data-parsley-trigger="change"
                             data-parsley-minlength="6"
                             data-parsley-equalto="#password"
                             required="required" />
                  </div>
              </div>
          </fieldset>
          <div class="form-actions">
              <button type="submit" data-ng-click="AddNewUser($event)" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded pull-right">Validate &amp; Submit</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded">Cancel</button>
          </div>
      </form>
```

and this is my async validator:

```
 window.ParsleyExtend = {
    asyncValidators: {
        checkusername: {
            fn: function (xhr) {
                console.log($('[name="userName"]'));
                return 404 === xhr.status;

            },
            url: authService.serviceBase + 'api/account/CheckUserName/' //+ $('[name="userName"]').text()


            },
        checkemail: {
            fn: function (xhr) {

                console.log($('[name="email"]')); 

                return 404 === xhr.status;
            },
            url: authService.serviceBase + 'api/account/CheckEmail/'// + $('[name="email"]').text()
        }
    }
};
```

and this is how I validate the form:

```
  $scope.AddNewUser = function ($event) {

    $event.preventDefault();
    //THis resturns true allways when the remote validation is not valid,, but when other non remote valdiation happens is works fine
    $('#AddUserForm').parsley().validate();
    //and this if statement  resturns true allways even when the remote validation is not valid,, but when other non remote valdiation happens is works fine
    if ($('#AddUserForm').parsley().isValid()) {
        authService.saveRegistration($scope.user).then(function (response) {

            $scope.savedSuccessfully = true;

            // $scope.message = "User has been registered successfully, you will be redicted to login page in 2 seconds.";
            //startTimer();

        },
         function (response) {
             var errors = [];
             for (var key in response.data.modelState) {
                 for (var i = 0; i < response.data.modelState[key].length; i++) {
                     errors.push(response.data.modelState[key][i]);
                 }
             }
             $scope.message = "Failed to register user due to:" + errors.join(' ');
         });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

just found the answer.. I have to use asyncIsValid() and  asyncValidate() along with the normal isValid() and Validate() methods.. so the code will be as follows:

```
 $('#AddUserForm').parsley().asyncValidate();

if($('#AddUserForm').parsley().isValid() && $('#AddUserForm').parsley().isAsyncValid()) {

....}
```

Comment: "TypeError: form.parsley(...).isAsyncValid is not a function[Learn More]"

Answer (score 0):

I first check each field to make sure it is validated, if a field is not validated, my `ok` variable will be set to false.

Here is some sample code:

```
$(function() {
  var ok;
  $('#signup').parsley().on('field:validated', function() {
      ok = $('.parsley-error').length === 0;
    })
    .on('form:submit', function() {
      if (ok) return true;
      else return false;
    });
});

Parsley.addAsyncValidator('checkExists', function(xhr) {
  return false === xhr.responseJSON;
}, '/data-management/verify-data?filter=signup');
```